# Airflow DAGs with Tasks

Tags: airflow

I have like 30 tasks in one DAG. At times, I may want to run each task separately.Could anyone please let me know whether I can run the 30 tasks separately on a need basis?

Also, looks like either I can create a DAG with all the 30 tasks or create separate DAG each with one task. Which one is better? When to use one DAG with many tasks and when to use one DAG with one task (ending up with many DAGs)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can run a single airflow task using the CLI

From the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#run):

```
airflow tasks run [-h] [--cfg-path CFG_PATH] [--error-file ERROR_FILE] [-f]
                  [-A] [-i] [-I] [-N] [-l] [-m] [-p PICKLE] [--pool POOL]
                  [--ship-dag] [-S SUBDIR]
                  dag_id task_id execution_date_or_run_id
```

Choosing how to structure your dags and tasks will depend on the problem you are trying to solve

Comment: Thanks! So, I would be able to run one specific task in my DAG (which has many DAGS) only using CLI? Is it possible using Airflow UI? Could you please clarify?  Also, what is local executor? Can the same be achieved using local executor? Could you please share the code snippet for that? Thanks!

Comment: Local executor - is one of the [executor types](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/executor/index.html#executor-types) supported by airflow - the cli command is the same

Comment: You can re-run one task from the UI from either the task view or Graph view - click on the task and select the `run` option.

Comment: Thanks Much! Will try to run each task from the UI then.